# Logout user automatically when came in WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using WordPress blog in a site. When user login and redirects in blog, they will be logged out automatically. How can I handle this?

Comment: Can you please clear up your question and add more context?

Comment: I guess he means if you login you get redirected back to the login/logout screen without actually logging in

Comment: when i am login by a user,and user came in blog of word press plugin user automatically logout.

Comment: Done...
write Following in .htaccess file 
php_flag register_globals off

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wordpress framework for blog or make your website, than in that any other person shouldn't have permission to register on it, because if any other person will register than they can change content and data of your blog or website, and if you want to solve that problem than you have to add a side bar gadgets.